# How do I grab information from an API?

Tags: python, api, flask

So I ran into some problem when I tried to get information from an API, I can grab the names of each product, but well for one: When I try to return the "float" value (the price of the product) I get this error:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

This is my Python code:

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template
import datetime
import array

product = [
    "BROWN_MUSHROOM",
    "INK_SACK:3",  # cocao beans
    "INK_SACK:4",  # lapis lazuli
    "TARANTULA_WEB",
    "CARROT_ITEM",
    "ENCHANTED_POTATO",
    "ENCHANTED_SLIME_BALL",
    "ENCHANTED_GOLDEN_CARROT",
    "ENCHANTED_RED_MUSHROOM",
    "ENCHANTED_RABBIT_HIDE",
    "ENCHANTED_BIRCH_LOG",
    "ENCHANTED_GUNPOWDER",
    "ENCHANTED_MELON",
    "ENCHANTED_SUGAR",
    "CACTUS",
    "ENCHANTED_BLAZE_ROD",
    "ENCHANTED_CAKE",
    "PUMPKIN",
    "ENCHANTED_BROWN_MUSHROOM",
    "WHEAT",
    "ENCHANTED_RAW_SALMON",
    "ENCHANTED_GLISTERING_MELON",
    "PRISMARINE_SHARD",
    "PROTECTOR_FRAGMENT",
    "ENCHANTED_EMERALD",
    "ENCHANTED_SPIDER_EYE",
    "RED_MUSHROOM",
    "MUTTON",
    "ENCHANTED_MELON_BLOCK",
    "DIAMOND",
    "WISE_FRAGMENT",
    "COBBLESTONE",
    "SPIDER_EYE",
    "RAW_FISH",
    "ENCHANTED_PUFFERFISH",
    "POTATO_ITEM",
    "ENCHANTED_HUGE_MUSHROOM_1",  # enchanted brown mushroom block
    "ENCHANTED_COBBLESTONE",
    "ENCHANTED_HUGE_MUSHROOM_2",  # enchanted red mushroom block
    "PORK",
    "PRISMARINE_CRYSTALS",
    "ICE",
    "HUGE_MUSHROOM_1",  # brown mushroom block
    "HUGE_MUSHROOM_2",  # red mushroom block
    "LOG_2:1",  # dark oak
    "ENCHANTED_SNOW_BLOCK",
    "GOLDEN_TOOTH",
    "STRING",
    "RABBIT_FOOT",
    "REDSTONE",
    "ENCHANTED_CACTUS_GREEN",
    "ENCHANTED_CARROT_STICK",
    "ENCHANTED_LAPIS_LAZULI_BLOCK",
    "ENCHANTED_COOKIE",
    "ENCHANTED_ENDSTONE",
    "ENCHANTED_SAND",
    "ENCHANTED_STRING",
    "STRONG_FRAGMENT",
    "SLIME_BALL",
    "ENCHANTED_ACACIA_LOG",
    "SNOW_BALL",
    "ENCHANTED_EGG",
    "SAND",
    "RAW_CHICKEN",
    "ENCHANTED_LAPIS_LAZULI",
    "ENCHANTED_GHAST_TEAR",
    "ENCHANTED_COCOA",
    "SEEDS",
    "ENCHANTED_LEATHER",
    "ENCHANTED_SPONGE",
    "HAY_BLOCK",
    "FLINT",
    "INK_SACK",
    "WOLF_TOOTH",
    "ENCHANTED_SPRUCE_LOG",
    "ENCHANTED_ROTTEN_FLESH",
    "ENCHANTED_GRILLED_PORK",
    "ENCHANTED_NETHER_STALK",
    "ENCHANTED_REDSTONE_BLOCK",
    "ENCHANTED_QUARTZ_BLOCK",
    "GREEN_CANDY",
    "ENCHANTED_REDSTONE",
    "ENCHANTED_REDSTONE_LAMP",
    "GRAVEL",
    "MELON",
    "ENCHANTED_LAVA_BUCKET",
    "ENCHANTED_PACKED_ICE",
    "RAW_FISH:3",  # pufferfish
    "ENCHANTED_PRISMARINE_SHARD",
    "ENCHANTED_CARROT_STICK",
    "ENCHANTED_IRON_BLOCK",
    "BONE",
    "RAW_FISH:2",  # clownfish
    "RAW_FISH:1",  # raw salmon
    "REVENANT_FLESH",
    "ENCHANTED_PORK",
    "ENCHANTED_GLOWSTONE",
    "FEATHER",
    "NETHERRACK",
    "SPONGE",
    "BLAZE_ROD",
    "ENCHANTED_DARK_OAK_LOG",
    "YOUNG_FRAGMENT",
    "ENCHANTED_CLOWNFISH",
    "ENCHANTED_GOLD",
    "ENCHANTED_RAW_CHICKEN",
    "ENCHANTED_WATER_LILY",
    "LOG:1",  # spruce
    "CATALYST",
    "LOG:3",  # jungle
    "LOG:2",  # birch
    "ENCHANTED_GLOWSTONE_DUST",
    "ENCHANTED_INK_SACK",
    "ENCHANTED_CACTUS",
    "ENCHANTED_SUGAR_CANE",
    "ENCHANTED_COOKED_SALMON",
    "ENCHANTED_SEEDS",
    "LOG",  # oak
    "GHAST_TEAR",
    "ENCHANTED_ENDER_PEARL",
    "UNSTABLE_FRAGMENT",
    "PURPLE_CANDY",
    "ENCHANTED_FERMENTED_SPIDER_EYE",
    "ENCHANTED_GOLD_BLOCK",
    "ENCHANTED_JUNGLE_LOG",
    "ENCHANTED_FLINT",
    "IRON_INGOT",
    "ENCHANTED_EMERALD_BLOCK",
    "ENCHANTED_CLAY_BALL",
    "GLOWSTONE_DUST",
    "GOLD_INGOT",
    "REVENANT_VISCERA",
    "TARANTULA_SILK",
    "ENCHANTED_MUTTON",
    "SUPER_EGG",
    "SUPER_COMPACTOR_3000",
    "ENCHANTED_IRON",
    "STOCK_OF_STONKS",
    "ENCHANTED_HAY_BLOCK",
    "ENCHANTED_BONE",
    "ENCHANTED_PAPER",
    "ENCHANTED_DIAMOND_BLOCK",
    "SUPERIOR_FRAGMENT",
    "EMERALD",
    "ENCHANTED_RABBIT_FOOT",
    "ENCHANTED_ICE",
    "HOT_POTATO_BOOK",
    "CLAY_BALL",
    "OLD_FRAGMENT",
    "GREEN_GIFT",
    "PACKED_ICE",
    "WATER_LILY",  # lily pad
    "LOG_2",  # acacia
    "HAMSTER_WHEEL",
    "ENCHANTED_OBSIDIAN",
    "ENCHANTED_COAL",
    "ENCHANTED_QUARTZ",
    "COAL",
    "ENDER_PEARL",
    "ENCHANTED_COAL_BLOCK",
    "ENCHANTED_PRISMARINE_CRYSTALS",
    "ENCHANTED_WET_SPONGE",
    "ENDER_STONE",  # end stone
    "ENCHANTED_RAW_FISH",
    "QUARTZ",
    "FOUL_FLESH",
    "RAW_BEEF",
    "ENCHANTED_EYE_OF_ENDER",
    "SUGAR_CANE",
    "MAGMA_CREAM",
    "RED_GIFT",
    "ENCHANTED_RAW_BEEF",
    "ENCHANTED_SLIME_BLOCK",
    "ENCHANTED_FEATHER",
    "ENCHANTED_OAK_LOG",
    "RABBIT_HIDE",
    "WHITE_GIFT",
    "RABBIT",
    "NETHER_STALK",
    "SULPHUR",
    "ENCHANTED_CARROT",
    "ENCHANTED_PUMPKIN",
    "ROTTEN_FLESH",
    "ENCHANTED_COOKED_FISH",
    "OBSIDIAN",
    "ENCHANTED_MAGMA_CREAM",
    "ENCHANTED_FIREWORK_ROCKET",
    "LEATHER",
    "ENCHANTED_COOKED_MUTTON",
    "ENCHANTED_RABBIT",
    "ENCHANTED_BREAD",
    "ENCHANTED_CHARCOAL",
    "ENCHANTED_BLAZE_POWDER",
    "SUMMONING_EYE",
    "SNOW_BLOCK",
    "ENCHANTED_BAKED_POTATO",
    "COMPACTOR",
    "ENCHANTED_DIAMOND"
]


app = Flask(__name__)

f = requests.get(
    "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=[not allowed to show key]").json()


itemName = f["products"]
for x in product:
    buyPrice = f["products"][x]["sell_summary"][0]["pricePerUnit"]


@app.route('/')
def price():
    return render_template("index.html", itemName=itemName, buyPrice=buyPrice)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now the "product" array I later saw was not really needed, because if I just do "itemName = f["products"]["product_id"]" it still writes all the product names, but I also want the prices. I somehow got it to work where it says the prices in one line (don't remember how), but if I do buyPrice = str(buyPrice) it looks like this on the webpage:
4
5
6
.
1

Which is not what I want, it also says the exact same numbers after every name, I want it to say the price of that exact product.

here is my HTML:

```
{% for item in itemName %}
    <h1>{{ item }}</h1>
    {% for price in buyPrice %}
    <h1>{{ price }}</h1>
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

And here is a link to the JSON API: https://jsonblob.com/b136acab-9ac0-11ea-add9-a360c1d2e6bd

So what I want it to do is just take the first name, then under the name print the sell and buy price, and some other information I can grab from the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some changes to your original code and got a working version that shows both the current buy/sell price of each product and its buy/sell historical prices.

```py
# app.py
import json
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def price():
    products_api_endpoint = "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=[not allowed to show key]"
    response = requests.get(products_api_endpoint).json()

    # I used a file for local testing because I didn't have access to the API you use
    # response = json.load(open("/tmp/response.json", "r")) 

    products = [
        {
            "id": product["product_id"],
            "sell_price": product["quick_status"]["sellPrice"],
            "buy_price": product["quick_status"]["buyPrice"],
            "sell_summary": product["sell_summary"],
            "buy_summary": product["buy_summary"]
        }
        for product in response["products"].values()
    ]
    # let's only send a few of them to the frontend (you can apply your own filtering here)
    # (comment-out next line if you want to show all the data at once)
    products = products[:3]  # filtering
    return render_template("index.html", products=products)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
<!-- templates/index.html -->

{% for product in products %}
    <p>
        <b>ID: {{ product.id }} -- sell price: {{ product.sell_price }} -- buy price: {{ product.buy_price }} </b>
        <p>
            Sell price history: &nbsp
            {% for sell in product.sell_summary %}
                {{ sell.pricePerUnit }}, &nbsp
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>
            Buy price history: &nbsp
            {% for buy in product.buy_summary %}
                {{ buy.pricePerUnit }}, &nbsp
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

It renders the results as shown in the following image. You can apply any CSS styles you wish to make it look prettier of course.

[image: Results]

Comment: ahhh thank you!!! Quick question, to remove the history, how do I do this? Or what do I use to remove that?

Comment: You can remove lines 6-15 of the HTML file. You can also remove lines 20 and 21 from app.py since they won't be needed anymore.

Comment: I am getting another issue here, now "product_id" doesn't exist, the API goes products -> then here is the product name -> quick_status. Which means that before ["quick_status"], we need ["products"] and [each product name], how do I solve this @Piero Hernandez ?

Comment: if you look at the python code I shared, inside the list comprehension it says `for product in response["products"].values()`, which accesses the `products` field of the response and takes all the `values()` of each of them. Can you somehow show your current code and error you're seeing?

Comment: here is my code: https://pastebin.com/Fbb8YW9u    And the errors im getting are "Keyerror: x" and x was first "product_id" but I change "product_id" to "products", and now it says "quick_status". I think it is because its looking for "quick_status", but as the json is products -> product name -> quick_status, it cant find it because "product name" is in the way. Bit hard to explain but hopefully my code could help out!

Comment: You had an error regarding variable names, here's the corrected version: https://pastebin.com/hBMZJ0LA. Compare it carefully to your so you understand what mistakes were made

Comment: Hey @Piero Hernandez , there are some problems with the API, now the prices from "quick_status" are incorrect and therefor I need the price from "pricePerUnit", did my best to try to solve it but didn't figure it out! Would you mind helping me over at https://stackoverflow.com/q/61955050/13581693 ? :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `buyPrice` is a single float value, corresponding to `12.7` in the data you give us. Then, in your template, you're trying to iterate over it by doing `for price in buyPrice`, which throws the error.

Depending on what you want to do, you should either extract the `pricePerUnit` values into an array that you can then use in the template, or modify the template to expect only a single float value.

Comment: okay, yeah I tried to get all values I want into an array, and it didn't really work because it only wrote the first one than just "stopped" the for loop, didn't spend that much time on it though so probably should try a bit more. Would you recommend that I either make one array with all content, or multiple array's? such as "buyPrice" "sellPrice" etc? And then finally return each value to my HTML?

Comment: Okay so I gave it a try, and got positive results (probably did something wrong the first time), now I am getting every single buyPrice value, but it says for example "BROWN_MUSHROOM" then every price for every product, how do you "lock" it into the product your looking for? What I mean by that is that I only want 15.3 on brown_mushroom, and x on diamond etc

Comment: Not sure what you mean - can you clarify?

Comment: Let me link you my code, here is html: https://pastebin.com/ssUxnjN9 , here is python: https://pastebin.com/2q800y7V and here is the output: https://pastebin.com/N7gKG3KF  (only took the first few ones)   Know as you can see it prints out the product names normally, but it prints all prices for each product, on each product. I wan't it to print the price on mushroom (14.7), then ink_sack:3 (5.5) and ink_sack:4 (4.2) and so on.

Comment: Where are you getting the values for each of those? I don't see those values in the data you gave in your question. If you just want the first one (or a particular indexed one), just fill you `buyPrice` array with only the values you want to display for each one. This is now, however, outside the scope of the original question, so I'd suggest searching on SO for similar questions or asking a new one. Make sure to accept this answer if it helped you out!

Comment: The values comes from the API, each product in the API has a Sell and Buy summary, where there is total orders, amount and pricePerUnit, now it is "pricePerUnit" I am looking for, and well as I said, the issue now is that it prints all the prices for every product, on each product. I want it to print the correct price for every product. I will give it a few more tries, some research etc, I at least got it working to be on the page! Thanks

Comment: For sure, I would check that you're also grabbing the right field from the data returned. Glad it helped you out a bit :)